# How to get the connection pool logs in spring boot

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, connection-pool

I have deployed my war in AWS and is very slow right now. I want to figure out following things in spring boot:

1. Which connection pool is used in spring boot apps?
2. How to log connection pool information in spring boot app? Right now, I got is spring.datasource.log-abandoned. Is there any? I want to log information like how many are idle and how many are active etc.
3. What is the minimum and maximun number of connections that can be active and idle in the current connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not place any other pooling data source implementation on the classpath and you're running in embedded tomcat (AND your data source is auto configured) spring boot will use the Tomcat pooling data source.

Exact algorithm is described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database

Most pooling implementations also expose JMX beans so you can get comprehensive stats and monitoring using JConsole. Tomcat one has JMX stats for sure.

Comment: Would you please explain more detail about connecting the stats?